# TextView exceeds screen size. Multiline?

Tags: android, view, imageview

I'm having problems with my layout. I have a TableLayout which contains two ImageViews and one TextView. The intention is to put the TextView between both ImageViews. The problem is that the TextView is "eating" all the screen space and the second image is invisible. In addition, it doesn't show all the text it should, doesn't have space. My code:

```
<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/table">
    <TableRow android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:background="@drawable/web_feed"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/lbltitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="#ff000000"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
             />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imagearrow"
            android:background="@drawable/icon_go"
            android:maxHeight="10dp"
            android:maxWidth="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/lblauthor"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:textColor="@color/primaryDark"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/lbldate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:gravity="end" />
</TableLayout>
```

So, what can I do to see the three columns and get the TextView multiline so all the text be visible?

I had solved partially the problem with:

```
table.setColumnShrinkable(1,true);
```

But the third image is still invisible.

Comment: use `android:layout_weight="1"` for your Textview

Comment: @Strider, what does `weight = 1` do ?

Answer (score 0):

That is because, your TextView's width is match_parent

```
    <TextView android:id="@+id/lbltitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#ff000000"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
     />
```

Instead of that, provide appropriate dp value for your textview.

Also, if you don't want to do that, Provide

```
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:singleLine="false"
```

Comment: Android Studio warning me to set the unit to sp. I reduce the number but the result is the same. Thanks

Comment: ok, if you want your Textview make specific number of lines all the time, use android:lines="3" and otherwise change its width to android:layout_width="wrap_content"

Answer (score 0):

change your `<TextView>` to:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"           
        android:textColor="#ff000000"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

the `android:layout_weight="1"` is important